# Pointers to undefined functions and parameters in C ++

Tags: c++

I have the following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

void saludo();
void despedida();

int main(){
    void (*Ptr_Funciones[2])() = {saludo, despedida};
    (Ptr_Funciones[0])();
    (Ptr_Funciones[1])();

    return 0;
}

void saludo(){
    cout<<"\nHola mundo";
}

void despedida(){
    cout<<"\nAdios mundo"<<endl<<endl;
}
```

Based on this, a few questions were generated which I investigated before asking but did not fully understand.

The questions are:

1. How do I make an array of functions, if they are of a different type?
2. I know that in C ++ this notation is used for undetermined parameters: (type var ...) The
   thing is, I don't know how to interact with them inside the function.
3. If questions 1 and 2 are possible, can these points be combined when creating function
   arrays?

I really have investigated. But I can't find much information, and the little I did find I didn't understand very well. I hope you can collaborate with me.

Thank you very much.

Comment: All elements of an array must be of the same type. That's just part of the definition of an array.

Comment: True, though one could use an array of pointers to functions that take C-style variadic parameters, or an array of `std::variant` holding different types of function pointers.  But really, what good is making an array of different types of functions? How do you expect to know which function to call with which parameters?

Comment: If the functions have different arguments but there is a way to hide them behind another set of functions with the same signature, you could wrap them in lambdas and store them in the array as `std::function<...>` or a fnptr type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I make an array of functions, if they are of a different type?

You can, but you don't want to. It doesn't make semantic sense. An array is a collection of the same *kind* of thing. If you find that you need to make a collection of different kinds of things, there are several data structures at your disposal.

> I know that in C++ this notation is used for undetermined parameters: (type var ...) The thing is, I don't know how to interact with them inside the function.

[Here](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variadic)'s how you can use the syntax you mention. They're called variadic functions.

> If questions 1 and 2 are possible, can these points be combined when creating function arrays?

Erm, I can't imagine why/when a combination of these two would be needed, but out of intellectual curiosity, awayyy we go...

A modified version of the code from the reference link above that kinda does what you want (i've used a map instead of an array, cuz why not):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <unordered_map>

template<typename T>
using fooptr = void (*) (T *t...);

struct A {
    const char *fmt;
    
    A(const char *s) :fmt{s} {}
};

struct B : public A {

    B(const char *s) : A{s} {}
};

void simple_printf(A *a...)
{
    va_list args;
    auto fmt = a->fmt;
    va_start(args, a);
 
    while (*fmt != '\0') {
        if (*fmt == 'd') {
            int i = va_arg(args, int);
            std::cout << i << '\n';
        } else if (*fmt == 'c') {
            // note automatic conversion to integral type
            int c = va_arg(args, int);
            std::cout << static_cast<char>(c) << '\n';
        } else if (*fmt == 'f') {
            double d = va_arg(args, double);
            std::cout << d << '\n';
        }
        ++fmt;
    }
 
    va_end(args);
}
 

int main()
{
    A a{"dcff"};
    B b{"dcfff"};

    std::unordered_map<size_t, fooptr<struct A>> index;
    index[1] = simple_printf;
    index[5] = simple_printf;
    
    index[1](&a, 3, 'a', 1.999, 42.5);
    index[5](&b, 4, 'b', 2.999, 52.5, 100.5);
}
```

This *still* really doesn't do what you wanted (i.e., give us the ability to choose from different functions during runtime). Bonus points if you understand why that's the case and/or how to fix it to do what you want.

Comment: It's impressive that you still know how to do varargs (C programmer?). I really don't want to be teaching this.

Answer (score 2):

Use a type alias to make things readable:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d366d68939a478d)**

```
using Signature = void();
Signature* Ptr_Funciones[] = { saludo, despedida };
```

Prints

```
Hola mundo
Adios mundo
```

### More flexible:

You can also use a vector:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c96b21f2343818ba)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void saludo() { cout << "\nHola mundo"; }
void despedida() { cout << "\nAdios mundo" << endl << endl; }

int main() {
    vector Ptr_Funciones = { saludo, despedida };

    Ptr_Funciones.front()();
    Ptr_Funciones.back()();
}
```

Prints the same.

### More Flexibility: Calleables of Different Types

To bind different types of functions, type-erasure should be used. `std::function` helps:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/99c9d4cd0f4056f0)**

```
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

void saludo(int value) { cout << "\nHola mundo (" << value << ")"; }
std::string despedida() { cout << "\nAdios mundo" << endl << endl; return "done"; }

int main() {
    vector<function<void()>>
        Ptr_Funciones {
            bind(saludo, 42),
            despedida
        };

    Ptr_Funciones.front()();
    Ptr_Funciones.back()();
}
```

Prints

```
Hola mundo (42)
Adios mundo
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is one solution that is possible, whether it fits your needs I'm not sure.

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void saludo()
{
    std::cout << "\nHola mundo"  << std::endl;;
}

void despedida()
{
    std::cout << "\nAdios mundo"  << std::endl;
}

void* fnPtrs[2];

typedef void* (VoidFunc)();

int main()
{
    fnPtrs[0] = saludo;
    fnPtrs[1] = despedida;

    ((VoidFunc*)fnPtrs[0])();
    ((VoidFunc*)fnPtrs[1])();

    std::getchar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the question in any way